# Persistence of saturation closure

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring. A closure operation $cl$ on a set of ideals $\mathcal{I}$ of
$R$ is a set map $cl: \mathcal{I}\longrightarrow \mathcal{I}( I\mapsto I^{cl})$ satisfying the following conditions:

(i) (Extension) $I \subseteq I^{cl}$ for all $I \in \mathcal{I}$

(ii) (Order-preservation) If $J \subseteq I$, then $J^{cl} \subseteq I^{cl}$ for all $J,I \in \mathcal{I}$

(iii) (Idempotence) $I^{cl}=(I^{cl})^{cl}$ for all $I \in \mathcal{I}$.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a subcategory of the category of commutative
rings. then a closure operation $cl$ is said to be 
persistent on $\mathcal{C}$ if for any ring homomorphism $\phi:R\longrightarrow R'$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and any ideal $I$ of $R$, one has
$$\phi(I^{cl})R'\subseteq (\phi(I)R')^{cl}.$$

Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a fixed ideal of $R$. Then $\mathfrak{a}$-saturation is a closure operation on a set of ideals $\mathcal{I}$ of $R$ defined as 
$$I^{cl}:= \bigcup_{n \in N}(I : \mathfrak{a}^n) = \{ x \in R\ |\ \exists\ n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } \mathfrak{a}^{n}x \subseteq I \}$$ for $I\in \mathcal{I}$. In the paper 'A GUIDE TO CLOSURE OPERATIONS IN COMMUTATIVE
ALGEBRA' (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1119.pdf) by Neil Epstein, it is stated that saturation closure (with respect to the maximal ideal) is persistent on
the subcategory of local rings and local homomorphisms. However, I could only show persistence on the subcategory of local rings and surjective local homomorphisms. I needed the assumption of surjection to use the fact that $\phi(m_R)=m_{R'}$ where $m_R$ and $m_{R'}$ are the maximal ideals of the local rings $R$ and $R'$ respectively. Could someone help me to show the persistence of saturation closure without the assumption of surjection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In retrospect that was rather silly of me to say that.  There is a version of the statement that is true (and that subsumes your surjection example), but the statement as stated is false.  Counterexample: Let $R=k[\![x,y]\!]$ and $S = k[\![x,y,z]\!]$.  Let $I := (x^2, xy)$.  Then $x \in I^{sat} \setminus (IS)^{sat}$.

Comment: Better counterexample: $R = k[x]/(x^2)$, $S=R[\![y]\!]$, $I=$ the zero ideal of $R$.  Then $x$ is in the saturation of $I$ but not of $IS$.  In any case, sorry for the error.

Comment: @Neil Epstein : Could you provide me with a reference where I can find that another version of the statement that is true, which subsumes the surjection example?

Comment: I don't know a reference, no.  But it goes like this.  Let $\cal C$ be a category whose objects are (certain) pairs $(R,J_R)$, where $R$ is a ring, $J_R$ is an ideal of $R$, and morphisms of $\mathcal C$ consist of (certain) ring homomorphisms $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ such that $\phi(J_R)S = J_S$.  Then for any morphism $\phi: (R,J_R) \rightarrow (S,J_S)$ in $\cal C$ and any ideal $I$ of $R$, $\phi(I^{J_R-{\rm sat}})S \subseteq (\phi(I)S)^{J_S-{\rm sat}}$.